# Sort elements from item class

Tags: java

I have an `Item` class which has `id`, `count`, `name` as instance variables. I want to sort the items based on count. Please tell me how to go about it. Any method which I can define in my item class to sort the items?

Below is my item class

```java
public class Item {

    private String id;
    private String count;
    private String name;

    Item() {
    }

    public String getcount() {
        return this.count;
    }

    public Item(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = "";

    }

    public Item(String id, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;

    }
    
    public Item(String id, String name,String count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.count=count;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getItemId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void createItem(String id, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Item returnItems(ItemList itemset) {
        Item item = null;

        return item;
    }
}
```

And I have an `ItemList` class as well, which holds items.

```java
public class ItemList implements Iterable<Item> {

    private List<Item> hold = new ArrayList<Item>();

    ItemList(Item item) {

        // hold = new ArrayList<Item>();
        this.hold.add(item);
    }

    ItemList() {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    public List<Item> getItemList() {
        return this.hold;

    }

    public void addItems(Item item) {
        //hold = new ArrayList<Item>();
        this.hold.add(item);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
        Iterator<Item> item = hold.iterator();
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you search in google before asking here? https://www.google.es/search?q=sort+class+in+java. There is a lot of information out there ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the Comparable interface.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 2):

Implement Comparable interface and write your logic for sorting order.

```
     public class Item implements Comparable<Item>{
      private String id;
      private String count;
      private String name;

      Item() {}
      ...    
      public int compareTo(Item item1) {
        return this.count.compareTo(item1.count);
      }   
    }
```

Now you can sort your List or array by `Collections#sort` or `Arrays#sort`.

Comment: Strange, but `count` attribute is `String`, not a number.

Comment: Thanks for notice. I really missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Your class should implements [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and the [compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method. Here's an [example](http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-comparable-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom comparator and use

```
Collections.sort(collections, yourComparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) for sorting objects.

In particular you should decide whether you need to:

1. implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface (for *natural* sorting - e.g. in a normally ordered collection) or
2. write your own [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) (if you're going to sort in many different ways i.e. by different fields in different scenarios)

Note you can do both if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

**-** Use `java.lang.Comparable` Interface, if you want to sort it in **only 1 way**.

**-** Use `java.util.Comparator` Interface, if you want to sort it in **more than 1 way**.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`Collections#sort`](http://tinyurl.com/8err8ej) and a `Comparator`:

```
List<Item> lstItem = new ArrayList<Item>();
//fill the data...
Comparator<Item> comparator = new Comparator<Item>() {
    public int compareTo(Item i1, Item i2) {
        return i1.count.compareTo(i2.count);
    }
};
Collections.sort(lstItem, comparator);
```